# Increasing WS Promise timeout

Tags: rest, playframework-2.0

I'm calling a REST ws that takes more time than 5 seconds and I'm getting a timeout for the Promise response. How can I increase this time above 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a Long to the get method of the promise that corresponds to the timeout of this method. For example:

```
promise.get(120000L);
```

would set a 2 minutes timeout for the get method.